# Exception message: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, itext

I am generating a pdf using the code below. Then it populates a gridview so that the user can click on the PDF that was just generated. I am getting an Exception message: `Exception type: IOException`

> The process cannot access the file '\Server\PDFs\PE10091026-Rev.pdf'
>   because it is being used by another process.

If I generate another PDF then the previous one can be opened.

Any idea what is holding the lock on it if no one has the file open?

```
Dim Doc1 As New Document
Dim path As String = "\\server\PDFs\"
Dim myUniqueFileName = String.Format("{0}.pdf", Session("FileName") & "-Rev")
Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc1, New FileStream(path & myUniqueFileName, FileMode.Create))

Doc1.Open()
Dim test As String
test = Session("PDF")
Dim PDFHeader As String
PDFHeader = Session("Header")
Dim imagepath As String = Server.MapPath(".") & "/images/Header.png"
Dim image As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath)
image.ScalePercent(70.0F)
Dim line1 As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw.LineSeparator(0.0F, 100.0F, BaseColor.BLACK, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1)

Doc1.Add(image)
Doc1.Add(New Paragraph(PDFHeader))
Doc1.Add(New Chunk(line1))
Doc1.Add(New Paragraph(test))
Doc1.Close()
Doc1.Dispose()
```

Comment: I don't see where you use the pdfWrite object.  Does it need to be closed and/or disposed?  Also, in the constructor for the PdfWrite, you create a new FileStream.  That creates and opens the file.  How is that file stream closed?

Comment: I did try filestream.dispose but it is not available as an option

Comment: You need to store the FileStream in a variable so you can call it's Close or Dispose method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to dispose the `FileStream` using `FileStream.Dispose()` or by using a `Using` statement. Currently the  `FileStream` is still opened in *create* mode when you try to open it the second time.

```
Using fs As New FileStream(Path & myUniqueFileName, FileMode.Create)

    Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc1, fs)
    Doc1.Open()

    Dim test As String
    test = Session("PDF")
    Dim PDFHeader As String
    PDFHeader = Session("Header")
    Dim imagepath As String = Server.MapPath(".") & "/images/Header.png"
    Dim image As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath)
    image.ScalePercent(70.0F)
    Dim line1 As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw.LineSeparator(0.0F, 100.0F, BaseColor.BLACK, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1)

    Doc1.Add(image)
    Doc1.Add(New Paragraph(PDFHeader))
    Doc1.Add(New Chunk(line1))
    Doc1.Add(New Paragraph(test))
    Doc1.Close()
    Doc1.Dispose()

End Using
```

Comment: I already do use Doc1.Dispose as shown above. I did try filestream.dispose but it is not available as an option

Comment: You disposed Doc1, but not pdfWrite.